# Pro Tools and Adobe Premiere

Tags: pro-tools, adobe, compatibility, daw

I have an independent gig coming up where they're editing in Adobe Premiere Pro CS4. Has anyone had any experience passing files between Premiere and Pro Tools (8.0.1)? Would you record to camera or could a portable recorder suffice (doesn't have time code, film length 5-10 min.)?

If you've had any compatibility or sync issues between the two, I'd love to know. It would be nice to prevent any problems before shooting begins to lessen my frustration later on.

Thanks,

Matt Cavanaugh

Comment: What platform are the two running on?  I know that it is really smooth when both are on Mac OS 10.5 and above.

Comment: Sorry it took a while, Iain, I never get notified for comments. I'm on a Mac with 10.5.8 and he's on a PC with ???. We ended up recording to portable rather than in camera. There really weren't compatibility issues since he would just export to Quicktime (which I did have to convert, but I think that's a different issue) and I'd throw my audio into Pro Tools, depending on which take each shot was for, and match it. Really the only problem was that it was ridiculously time consuming... and that there was no pay involved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking audio recorders generate better audio than video cameras, although sometimes in indie production the director or picture editor request that audio is recorded in the camera to skip the syncing process, in that case, use a portable mixer, don't go straight to the camera.
You can also use a mixer to feed both a portable audio recorder as well as the camera for safety purposes. 
All shots have to be slated of course, if so is not possible a tail slate at the end of the take **MUST** be recorded before the picture and audio cuts.

As far as the picture editing software, the work flow for me has been exactly the same, wether the picture was cut in Avid, Final cut, or premiere; You get the picture and the omf or aaf from the picture editor. Remember to ask the picture editor to export the omf or aaf with "infinite" handles so that you have access to the whole takes, not just the bits that the picture editor used. Also make sure to setup your frame rate to the picture frame rate in the session menu (apple+2- on the numeric pad)

Not sure if i've answered the question...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Filipe. That's great information. I'll be sure to pass it on to the everyone.